# Android 4.0 SSL Authentication

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, android-authenticator

I'm trying to build an RSS feed reader that needs to do some client side SSL authentication.

I've got, or at least think I have, the certificate. However I now cannot figure out how to setup a ssl tunnel to send the certificate to the server to authenticate.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Authenticator extends Activity {

PrivateKey privateKey = null;
String SavedAlias = "";
private static final String TAG = "AUTHENTICATOR.CLASS";
final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
private KeyStore mKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance();

public Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

public void run()
{
   mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          new AliasLoader().execute();
      }
   });
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getCertificates("TEST");
}

public class AliasLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, X509Certificate[]> 
{
    X509Certificate[] chain = null;

    @Override protected X509Certificate[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

        if(!SavedAlias.isEmpty())
        {
                try {
                    chain = KeyChain.getCertificateChain(getApplicationContext(),SavedAlias);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
        }
        else
        {
            this.cancel(true);
        }

        return chain;
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(X509Certificate[] chain) 
    {

        if(chain != null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YAY, Certificate is not empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Certificate is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        /*
        if (privateKey != null) {
            Signature signature = null;
            try {
                signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            try {
                signature.initSign(privateKey);
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        */
    }
}

public void getCertificates(String Host)
{
    KeyChainAliasCallback callBack = new KeyChainAliasCallback() {

        @Override
        public void alias(String alias) {               
            if (alias != null) 
            {
                Looper.prepare();
                saveAlias(alias);
                run();
                Looper.loop();
            }
        }
    };

    KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias(this, callBack,
    new String[] {"RSA", "DSA"}, // List of acceptable key types. null for any
    null,                        // issuer, null for any
    null,      // host name of server requesting the cert, null if unavailable
    443,                         // port of server requesting the cert, -1 if unavailable
    null);                       // alias to preselect, null if unavailable
}

public void saveAlias(String alias)
{
    SavedAlias = alias;
}
}
```

Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated as i have never done any authentication before and i have found it difficult to find anything on this topic for android 4.0 as 4.0 seems to be different in implementation then the older versions.

Comment: Try this one: http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/04/one-solution-for-android-tlsssl-client-authentication/

Comment: Thanks Robert, that link looks like it gives me almost everything i need to get this working.


The only thing im struggling with the class on the link, is it gets the certificate from the devices raw resource, whereas in my case ive got the certificate installed to the systems trust store in the users container. 


My code gets the certificate as a X509Certificate[] but i dont know how i can load it into the keystore we create in the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve the certificate chain as well as the private key and store it into a temporary in-memory `KeyStore`:

```
String alias = "test";
KeyStore memoryKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
memoryKeyStore.load(null);
X509Certificate[] chain = KeyChain.getCertificateChain(getApplicationContext(),alias);
PrivateKey key = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(getApplicationContext(),alias);
memoryKeyStore.setKeyEntry(alias, key.getEncoded(), chain);
```

Afterwards you can use this key store for initializing the SSLContext instance.

Warning: Note the sample code contains an `X509TrustManager` implementation that does not perform server certificate validation. Better not use it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it has helped greatly. im still getting issues but at least now its got the certificate and trying to do the handshake to the server using the certicate.

thats where it fails, although the code doesnt produce any errors i cannot gain access, but im sure its just some problem with either the way im sending the certificates or because the authentication is getting screwed up somewhere =)

Comment: @Deep.Timon did you get it working with this code? I have the same problem where my client certificate is not being validated by the server, although it is sent to the server. It doesn't produce any errors as well. In my case both the client and server certificates are signed by the same rootCA, and I simply don't know why the handshake doesn't work. Please share if you have any solution

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution won't work in 4.1+. There the private key is not exportable and it is not possible to put it in the in-memory key store.
Check [How to make client certificate authentication from Android 4.1 with Apache client and the KeyChain API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363940/how-to-make-client-certificate-authentication-from-android-4-1-with-apache-clien)
on how to do it in 4.1