# How to make client certificate authentication from Android 4.1 with Apache client and the KeyChain API

Tags: android, ssl, keystore

Since ICS Android supports unified access to the system keystore and trusted CAs via the KeyChain API.

It is quite nice but is giving me following trouble when I try to use a private key from this source for client cert authentication.

I checked some answers here and the best thing that I found was: [Android 4.0 SSL Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581208/android-4-0-ssl-authentication)

It refers to 4.0 and provides following coding:

Update - this coding is WRONG - it will not work in 4.1+

```
String alias = "test";
KeyStore memoryKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
memoryKeyStore.load(null);
X509Certificate[] chain = KeyChain.getCertificateChain(getApplicationContext(),alias);
PrivateKey key = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(getApplicationContext(),alias);
memoryKeyStore.setKeyEntry(alias, key.getEncoded(), chain);
```

this is however not working in 4.1 because the PrivateKey object returned by KeyChain.getPrivateKey() returns null when the getEncoded() method is called and the KeyStore cannot be initialized.

Is there any other way to do this in 4.1?

Update - here the correct way to define your own implementation of KeyStore and KeyStoreSpi
Here the sample implementation of KeyStore and KeyStoreSpi:

KeyStoreSpi implementation:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.KeyStoreSpi;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;

import java.security.PrivateKey;

public class KeyChainProxy extends KeyStoreSpi {


  private String alias = null;
  private PrivateKey privateKey = null;
  private Certificate[] certChain = null;

  public KeyChainProxy(String alias, PrivateKey privateKey, Certificate[] certChain) {
    this.alias = alias;
    this.privateKey = privateKey;
    this.certChain = certChain;
  }

  @Override
  public Key engineGetKey(String alias, char[] password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    return privateKey;
  }

  @Override
  public Certificate[] engineGetCertificateChain(String alias) {
    return certChain;
  }

  @Override
  public Certificate engineGetCertificate(String alias) {
    return certChain[0];
  }

  @Override
  public Date engineGetCreationDate(String alias) {
    return new Date();
  }

  @Override
  public void engineSetKeyEntry(String alias, Key key, char[] password, Certificate[] chain) throws KeyStoreException {
    throw new KeyStoreException("Not Implemented");

  }

  @Override
  public void engineSetKeyEntry(String alias, byte[] key, Certificate[] chain) throws KeyStoreException {
    throw new KeyStoreException("Not Implemented");

  }

  @Override
  public void engineSetCertificateEntry(String alias, Certificate cert) throws KeyStoreException {
    throw new KeyStoreException("Not Implemented");

  }

  @Override
  public void engineDeleteEntry(String alias) throws KeyStoreException {
    throw new KeyStoreException("Not Implemented");

  }

  @Override
  public Enumeration<String> engineAliases() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(alias);
    return Collections.enumeration(list);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean engineContainsAlias(String alias) {
    return alias != null && alias.equals(this.alias);
  }

  @Override
  public int engineSize() {
    return 1;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean engineIsKeyEntry(String alias) {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean engineIsCertificateEntry(String alias) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public String engineGetCertificateAlias(Certificate cert) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void engineStore(OutputStream stream, char[] password) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException {

  }

  @Override
  public void engineLoad(InputStream stream, char[] password) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException {

  }

}
```

KeyStore implemenation:

```
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreSpi;
import java.security.Provider;

public class KeyChainKeystore extends KeyStore {

  public KeyChainKeystore(KeyStoreSpi keyStoreSpi, Provider provider, String type) {
    super(keyStoreSpi, provider, type);
    try {
      load(null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // ignore - our spi doesn't do anything
    }
  }
```

}

Thank you

Vasil

Comment: Can you just explain how do you use this two custom classes next? I am struggling with the same problem...

Comment: I figured it out. Here it is for the ones looking for this final piece: KeyChainProxy keyChainProxy = new KeyChainProxy("your-alias", yourKey, yourChain); KeyChainKeystore keyChainKeystore = new KeyChainKeystore(keyChainProxy, null, "type-of-keystore-you-want");

Comment: That's the idea. You can make an SPI out of the keychain and use it to init a keystore. Then you can use this keystore as client certificate in an ssl call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The KeyChain is designed to protect your private keys.

Therefore you can get a reference to a private key and use that private key within your app for authentication, encryption, ... but you never get access to the actual private key data.

Hence you can not export the private key - which is what you are trying to do.

Comment: What you say seems right but ... then why does the Apache client need an explicit KeyStore object in order to do client cert authentication? The trusted CAs of Android is available as KeyStore object via `KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore")` but the private keys are not.

Comment: Seems like the interfaces do not work well together. But there is stated nowhere that it has to be a BKS KeyStore instance. You could try to implement your own KeyStoreSpi instance that contains only the PrivateKey you got from the KeyChain. If the key is only used it may work.

Comment: Will try this and update the question with the result - thanks for your help.

Comment: Confirmed - this is working as advised - I'll update the answer with a sample implementation of the two classes - KeyStoreSPI and KeyStore